# how to match a string that contains multiple given words?

Tags: regex

The regex `/hello|world/` can match a string that contains hello OR world.

I want to match only strings that contain hello AND world in no particular order. I thought something like this could work but it didn't:

`/hello&world/`

The following should be matched:

`hello world`
`hello dear world`
`a hello b world c`
`world hello`

These should not match:

`world`
`hello`
`a world b`
`asdf`

How do I write this regex so it matches strings that contain multiple words?

Answer (score 0):

The following expression works on your strings:

```
/hello.*world|world.*hello/
```

Basically, it tests if a string contains ("hello" then "world") OR ("world" then "hello").
Note that this approach is not practical if you have many words.